# Storing spring integration routes in mongo for dynamism

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have a mongo repository with connectivity between multiple components. I have a traditional java application which reads the mongo repository and performs the routing, transformation by calling appropriate java classes dynamically. I am planning to move this to spring but do not want to statically declare routes as this is highly inflexible. Is there any possibility to make sure that spring can refer routes and transformations from mongo and performs the routing.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you are looking for but, yes, it's easy to create custom routers, transformers and/or other components.